# Using AJAX to load SQL table into HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying use AJAX to load multiple SQL queries into a HTML table. I've been using a tutorial for using AJAX to load values into an option box as my basis for this but cant get it to work.

AJAX script at bottom of HTML file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($) {
  var list_target_id = "tableDiv";
  var list_select_id = "year";
  var initial_target_html = "Fill in option boxes first";

  $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html);

  $('#'+list_select_id).change(function(e) {
    var year = $(this).val();
    var month = $(month).val();
    var companyID = $(company).val();

    if (year == "" && companyID == "" && month == "") {
       $('#'+list_target_id).html(initial_target_html);
    } else {
      $.ajax({url: 'ajax-getvalues2.php?month='+month+'&year='+year&companyID='+companyID,
             success: function(output) {

                $('#'+list_target_id).html(output);
            },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status + " "+ thrownError);
          }});
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

ajax-getvalues2.php:

```
<?php  
$connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "Query", "Query", "database1");

$companyID = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['companyID']);
$month = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['month']);
$year = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['year']);

$date = $year + "/" + $month + "/01";

$date1 = $date.setMonth(date.setMonth()-1);
$date2 = $date.setMonth(date.setMonth()-2);
$date3 = $date.setMonth(date.setMonth()-3);
$date4 = $date.setMonth(date.setMonth()-4);
$date5 = $date.setMonth(date.setMonth()-5);
$date6 = $date.setMonth(date.setMonth()-6);

echo     '<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-bordered">';

mysqli_select_db($connection, "database1");

$array = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT DISTINCT buildingList.siteName, buildingList.siteId FROM buildingList INNER JOIN meterList ON buildingList.siteId = meterList.siteId WHERE buildingList.companyID = '$companyID' AND meterList.meterType = '$meterType'");


for (i=0, i < array.length, i++){
$siteId = $array[i];


$q2= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT value FROM meterList WHERE siteId = '$siteId' AND meterType.meterList = '$meterType' AND date = '$date1'");
$q3= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT value FROM meterList WHERE siteId = '$siteId' AND meterType.meterList = '$meterType' AND date = '$date2'");
$q4= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT value FROM meterList WHERE siteId = '$siteId' AND meterType.meterList = '$meterType' AND date = '$date3'");
$q5= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT value FROM meterList WHERE siteId = '$siteId' AND meterType.meterList = '$meterType' AND date = '$date4'");
$q6= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT value FROM meterList WHERE siteId = '$siteId' AND meterType.meterList = '$meterType' AND date = '$date5'");
$q7= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT value FROM meterList WHERE siteId = '$siteId' AND meterType.meterList = '$meterType' AND date = '$date6'");

echo '<td>' array[i] "</td>";
echo '<td contenteditable='true' type="text"  onkeyup="consumption()">"  "</td>";
echo '<td>' .$row['q2']. '</td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td>' .$row['q3']. '</td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td>' .$row['q4']. '</td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td>' .$row['q5']. '</td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td>' .$row['q6']. '</td>';
echo '<td></td>';
echo '<td>' .$row['q7']. '</td>';
echo '<td></td>';

}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_free_result($result);
mysqli_close($connection);

?>
```

Month should be inputted into the php file as "01" for Jan and year should be inputted as "2016" for 2016. Then it should be combined to give a date such as year/month/01.

I'm not exactly sure where I've went wrong, but could I have some advice please. Thanks in advance:)

Comment: What exactly is working? Are you seeing an error? Is the data formatted incorrectly? You have to give us a clue as to what isn't working....

Comment: @SloanThrasher I've tried going onto my browser and going to http://localhost/ajax-getvalues2.php?month=04&year=2016&companyID=1 but the page just remains blank, I would have thought there to be something displayed

Comment: Enable error reporing

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I've added " ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); " onto the top line, but still nothing shows up when I go onto the webpage

Comment: Var_dump() your results

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I've stuck var_dump($date);  just after the real escape line but the page still loads as blank.

Comment: Which line are using to fetch results? All i can is query the db only, but ilu dont actually fetch the query results

Comment: @TakeoGFX: turn on error reporting in PHP, and call the script that AJAX calls with parameters. That should give you enough info to debug the script.

Comment: You do not have to turn on all error reporting. Try this as the first line of code in the file: error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_STRICT);

Answer (score 0):

Your script won't compile, so you aren't going to see anything. For instance, the line:

```
echo '<td>' array[i] "</td>";
```

should be:

```
echo '<td>' . array[i] . "</td>";
```

They may be other errors. The way to turn on error reporting for PHP errors is:

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_COMPILE_ERROR | E_STRICT);
```

Put on a line it right after the first \<\?php in your script.